# "undefined is not a function" error when calling fadeOut()

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    document.getElementById('hp-testimonials').fadeOut(500);
}
```

It just gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Why? A `<div>` with an `id` of "hp-testimonials" exists on the page. I don't understand why it wont fade this `<div>` out.

Comment: why wouldn't you use `$('#hp-testimonials')` ?

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns an HTML node, not a jQuery object. `fadeOut` only exists on a jQuery object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fadeOut()` isn't a standard DOM method; it's part of jQuery. You're trying to call it on a DOM element.

Instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#hp-testimonials').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you got the element using pure javascript which would mean jquery methods will not be available try `$('#hp-testimonials').fadeOut(500)` instead